# Getting dummies for both train and test data

Tags: encoding

Should I apply `pd.get_dummies()` for both train and test data? And would it not result in data leakage?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pandas.get_dummies` on the train and test data separately you will likely run into issues because it is likely that there are new values in the test dataset which are not in the training dataset. It is therefore better to use something like [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) which can save state and encode the test dataset based on the values that were seen in the training dataset.